# Reproducing encrypted video using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, encryption, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm using [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), in Android, and I'm trying to reproduce an encrypted video stored locally.

The modularity of ExoPlayer allows to create custom components that can be injected in the ExoPlayer, and this seems the case. Indeed, after some researches I realized that for achive that task I could create a custom DataSource and overriding `open()`, `read()` and `close()`.

I have also found [this solution](http://upshots.org/android/android-play-encrypted-video-in-exoplayer), but actually here the entire file is decrypted in one step and stored in a clear inputstream. This can be good in many situation. But what if I need to reproduce big file?

So the question is: how can I reproduce encrypted video in ExoPlayer, decrypting content "on-fly" (without decrypting the entire file)? Is this possibile?

I tried creating a custom DataSource that has the open() method:

```
@Override
    public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws FileDataSourceException {
        try {
            File file = new File(dataSpec.uri.getPath());

            clearInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), mCipher);

            long skipped = clearInputStream.skip(dataSpec.position);
            if (skipped < dataSpec.position) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            if (dataSpec.length != C.LENGTH_UNBOUNDED) {
                bytesRemaining = dataSpec.length;
            } else {
                bytesRemaining = clearInputStream.available();
                if (bytesRemaining == 0) {
                    bytesRemaining = C.LENGTH_UNBOUNDED;
                }
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        opened = true;
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onTransferStart();
        }

        return bytesRemaining;
    }
```

And this is the read() method:

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws FileDataSourceException {
        if (bytesRemaining == 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            int bytesRead = 0;

                int bytesToRead = bytesRemaining == C.LENGTH_UNBOUNDED ? readLength
                        : (int) Math.min(bytesRemaining, readLength);
            try {
                bytesRead = clearInputStream.read(buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                if (bytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNBOUNDED) {
                    bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
                }
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onBytesTransferred(bytesRead);
                }
            }

            return bytesRead;
        }
    }
```

If instead of an encoded file I pass a clear file, and just remove the CipherInputStream part, then it works fine, instead with encrypted file I obtain this error:

```
    Unexpected exception loading stream
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Top bit not zero: -1195853062
at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.ParsableByteArray.readUnsignedIntToInt(ParsableByteArray.java:240)
at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readSample(Mp4Extractor.java:331)
at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:122)
at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorSampleSource.java:745)
at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:209)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**EDIT**:

the encrypted video is generated in this way:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("0123456789012345".getBytes(), "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("0123459876543210".getBytes());
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

outputStream = new CipherOutputStream(output_stream, cipher);
```

Then the outputStream is saved into a File.

Comment: Do you have an encrypted video? Which encryption is it encrypted with?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: I would try to wrap `CipherInputStream` with `DataInputStream` and use `readFully()` instead of `read()`.

Comment: With DataInputStream I have the same problem

Comment: C.LENGTH_UNBOUNDED it is unresolved.. deprecated or which version of exoplayer were you using  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution.

I used a no-padding for the encryption algorithm, in this way:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
```

so that the size of the encrypted file and the clear file size remain the same. So now I created the stream:

```
cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher) {
    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
         return in.available();
    }
};
```

This is because the Java documentation says about `ChiperInputStream.available()` that

> [This method **should** be overriden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html#available())

and actually I think is it more like a MUST, because the values retrieved from that method are often really strange.

And that is it! Now it works perfectly.

Comment: can you plz update the link for the code... i m stuck on same issue and the above link is dead now.

Comment: first of all, Thanks for replying.. i am talking about `I have also found this solution, but actually here the entire file is decrypted` in your question.. not in this answer.

Comment: i have found demo project but its not working with `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` .. i think..

Comment: I am sorry, I son't know where to find a correct link. It use to work: after 3 and half years, I can't really remember that link.

Comment: Okay.. :( ...do you have any working demo code or something.. can you send me on dude.xda1@gmail.com .... i'll be really thankful to you. :)

Answer (score 5):

Example how to play encrypted audio file, hope this will help to someone.
I'm using Kotlin here

```
import android.net.Uri
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSpec
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions
import java.io.IOException
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream

class EncryptedDataSource(upstream: DataSource) : DataSource {

    private var upstream: DataSource? = upstream
    private var cipherInputStream: CipherInputStream? = null

    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec?): Long {
        val cipher = getCipherInitDecrypt()
        val inputStream = DataSourceInputStream(upstream, dataSpec)
        cipherInputStream = CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher)
        inputStream.open()
        return C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()

    }

    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray?, offset: Int, readLength: Int): Int {
        Assertions.checkNotNull<Any>(cipherInputStream)
        val bytesRead = cipherInputStream!!.read(buffer, offset, readLength)
        return if (bytesRead < 0) {
            C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
        } else bytesRead
    }

    override fun getUri(): Uri {
        return upstream!!.uri
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun close() {
        if (cipherInputStream != null) {
            cipherInputStream = null
            upstream!!.close()
        }
    }
}
```

In function above you need to get Cipher which was used for encryption and **init it**: smth like this

```
fun getCipherInitDecrypt(): Cipher {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
    val iv = IvParameterSpec(initVector.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")))
    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key, TYPE_RSA)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv)
    return cipher
}
```

Next step is creating `DataSource.Factory` for `DataSource` we've implemented earlier

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource

class EncryptedFileDataSourceFactory(var dataSource: DataSource) : DataSource.Factory {

    override fun createDataSource(): DataSource {
        return EncryptedDataSource(dataSource)
    }
}
```

And last step is players initialization

```
    private fun prepareExoPlayerFromFileUri(uri: Uri) {
        val player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                    DefaultTrackSelector(),
                    DefaultLoadControl())

        val playerView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.player_view)
        playerView.player = player

        val dsf = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerInfo"))
        //This line do the thing
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(EncryptedFileDataSourceFactory(dsf.createDataSource())).createMediaSource(uri)
        player.prepare(mediaSource)
    }
```

Comment: which version of exoplayer is running this ?

Answer (score 4):

This problem had me tearing my hair out, so I finally caved and implemented a streaming cipher for AES/CBC that lets you skip ahead. CBC theoretically allows for random reads, you need to initialize the cipher with the previous block's ciphertext as the initialization vector and then read ahead until the spot you needed. Sample project with full implementation [here.](https://github.com/Javi/AndroidCbcDecryptingExoplayer) Here's the key classes:

```
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSpec
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.TransferListener
import ar.cryptotest.exoplayer2.MainActivity.Companion.AES_TRANSFORMATION
import java.io.EOFException
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.lang.RuntimeException
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

const val TAG = "ENCRYPTING PROCESS"

class BlockCipherEncryptedDataSource(
    private val secretKeySpec: SecretKeySpec,
    private val uri: Uri,
    cipherTransformation: String = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
) : DataSource {
    private val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation)
    private lateinit var streamingCipherInputStream: StreamingCipherInputStream
    private var bytesRemaining: Long = 0
    private var isOpen = false
    private val transferListeners = mutableListOf<TransferListener>()
    private var dataSpec: DataSpec? = null

    @Throws(EncryptedFileDataSourceException::class)
    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {
        this.dataSpec = dataSpec

        if (isOpen) return bytesRemaining

        try {
            setupInputStream()
            streamingCipherInputStream.forceSkip(dataSpec.position)
            computeBytesRemaining(dataSpec)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e)
        }

        isOpen = true
        transferListeners.forEach { it.onTransferStart(this, dataSpec, false) }

        return C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
    }

    private fun setupInputStream() {
        val path = uri.path ?: throw RuntimeException("Tried decrypting uri with no path: $uri")
        val encryptedFileStream = File(path).inputStream()
        val initializationVector = ByteArray(cipher.blockSize)
        encryptedFileStream.read(initializationVector)
        streamingCipherInputStream =
            StreamingCipherInputStream(
                encryptedFileStream,
                cipher,
                IvParameterSpec(initializationVector),
                secretKeySpec
            )
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun computeBytesRemaining(dataSpec: DataSpec) {
        if (dataSpec.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
            bytesRemaining = dataSpec.length
            return
        }

        if (bytesRemaining == Int.MAX_VALUE.toLong()) {
            bytesRemaining = C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
            return
        }

        bytesRemaining = streamingCipherInputStream.available().toLong()
    }

    @Throws(EncryptedFileDataSourceException::class)
    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, readLength: Int): Int {
        if (bytesRemaining == 0L) {
            Log.e(TAG, "End - No bytes remaining")
            return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
        }

        val bytesRead = try {
            streamingCipherInputStream.read(buffer, offset, readLength)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e)
        }

        // Reading -1 means an error occurred
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            if (bytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong())
                throw EncryptedFileDataSourceException(EOFException())
            return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
        }

        // Bytes remaining will be unset if file is too large for an int
        if (bytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong())
            bytesRemaining -= bytesRead.toLong()

        dataSpec?.let { nonNullDataSpec ->
            transferListeners.forEach {
                it.onBytesTransferred(this, nonNullDataSpec, false, bytesRead)
            }
        }
        return bytesRead
    }

    override fun addTransferListener(transferListener: TransferListener) {
        transferListeners.add(transferListener)
    }

    override fun getUri(): Uri = uri

    @Throws(EncryptedFileDataSourceException::class)
    override fun close() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Closing stream")
        try {
            streamingCipherInputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e)
        } finally {
            if (isOpen) {
                isOpen = false
                dataSpec?.let { nonNullDataSpec ->
                    transferListeners.forEach { it.onTransferEnd(this, nonNullDataSpec, false) }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class EncryptedFileDataSourceException(cause: IOException?) : IOException(cause)
    class StreamingCipherInputStream(
        private val sourceStream: InputStream,
        private var cipher: Cipher,
        private val initialIvParameterSpec: IvParameterSpec,
        private val secretKeySpec: SecretKeySpec
    ) : CipherInputStream(
        sourceStream, cipher
    ) {
        private val cipherBlockSize: Int = cipher.blockSize

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun read(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int): Int = super.read(b, off, len)

        fun forceSkip(bytesToSkip: Long) {
            val bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock = bytesToSkip % cipherBlockSize

            val bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart =
                bytesToSkip - bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock - cipherBlockSize

            try {
                if (bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart <= 0) {
                    cipher.init(
                        Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                        secretKeySpec,
                        initialIvParameterSpec
                    )
                    return
                }

                var skipped = sourceStream.skip(bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart)
                while (skipped < bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart) {
                    sourceStream.read()
                    skipped++
                }

                val previousEncryptedBlock = ByteArray(cipherBlockSize)

                sourceStream.read(previousEncryptedBlock)

                cipher.init(
                    Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                    secretKeySpec,
                    IvParameterSpec(previousEncryptedBlock)
                )
                skip(bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart + cipherBlockSize)

                val discardableByteArray = ByteArray(bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock.toInt())
                read(discardableByteArray)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Encrypted video skipping error", e)
                throw e
            }
        }

        // We need to return the available bytes from the upstream.
        // In this implementation we're front loading it, but it's possible the value might change during the lifetime
        // of this instance, and reference to the stream should be retained and queried for available bytes instead
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun available(): Int {
            return sourceStream.available()
        }
    }
}

class BlockCipherEncryptedDataSourceFactory(
    private val secretKeySpec: SecretKeySpec,
    private val uri: Uri,
    private val cipherTransformation: String = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
) : DataSource.Factory {
    override fun createDataSource(): BlockCipherEncryptedDataSource {
        return BlockCipherEncryptedDataSource(secretKeySpec, uri, cipherTransformation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check your proxy, given the following configuration.

```
ALLOWED_TRACK_TYPES = "SD_HD"
content_key_specs = [{ "track_type": "HD",
                       "security_level": 1,
                       "required_output_protection": {"hdcp": "HDCP_NONE" }
                     },
                     { "track_type": "SD",
                       "security_level": 1,
                       "required_output_protection": {"cgms_flags": "COPY_FREE" }
                     },
                     { "track_type": "AUDIO"}]
request = json.dumps({"payload": payload,
                      "content_id": content_id,
                      "provider": self.provider,
                      "allowed_track_types": ALLOWED_TRACK_TYPES,
                      "use_policy_overrides_exclusively": True,
                      "policy_overrides": policy_overrides,
                      "content_key_specs": content_key_specs
                     ?
```

In the ExoPlayer demo app - DashRenderBuilder.java has a method 'filterHdContent' this always returns true if device is not level 1 (Assuming here it's L3). This causes the player to disregard the HD AdaptionSet in the mpd whilst parsing it.

You can set the filterHdContent to always return false if you want to play HD, however it is typical of content owners to require a L1 Widevine implementation for HD content.

check this link for more https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1116
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1523

Comment: I really didn't understand your answer. It seems not related to my problem, since it was just a problem in creating the DataSource in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a custom DataSource, with open/read/close, is a solution to your need. For an 'on-the-fly' decryption (valuable for big files but not only), you must design a streaming architecture.

There are already posts similar to yours. To find them, don't look for 'exoplayer', but 'videoview' or 'mediaplayer' instead. The answers should be compatible.

For instance, [Playing encrypted video files using VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831518/playing-encrypted-video-files-using-videoview)

Comment: Of course you can use a DataSource. ExoPlayer is designed in a modular way, so that a DataSource can be whatever you want. You can create your own implementation for retrieving the data from the network, from a Content  Provider, from a resource, from a file (encrypted or not), etc. So this is perfectly fine. Take a look at my answer for details.

Comment: by using custom paid library.. really?.. is it some kind of promotion ?