# Decrypt a video and play parallelly

Tags: java, android, aes

I encrypt a video using AES and stored in the sd card .
Now I'm able to decrypt the video and play but decryption is taking long time, so the I have to wait until whole video file get decrypted.

Is there any way by which I can decrypt and parallelly play the video without waiting for whole file decryption?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use ExoPlayer. I did it in my last project. I had some problem with the decription, but eventually I came up with a solution.

Basically you need to create your custom DataSource that gets data from your file, and on-fly decrypt those data and provides them to the Player. Here you can find the [ExoPlayer documentation](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html).

Here my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729220/reproducing-encrypted-video-using-exoplayer) with my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38729220/1584654).

**NOTE**: Consider that my DataSource was written for ExoPlayer 1.5.9. Just two days ago has been released (major) a new version 2.0.0 where they changed a lot of stuff in the ExoPlayer. So if you want use the new one I can't garantee that my custom DataSource will work (despite I expect it will xD).