# Online encrypted streaming video files with AES in exoplayer android

Tags: encryption, video-streaming, exoplayer

I have video files encrypted with AES stored on server. How to stream them online in exoplayer? I don't want to download the file and decrypt it: waiting for the download to complete and then play decrypted file.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at the `UriDataSource` or the `DataSource` interface. You can derive from `DataSource` and provide an implementation very similar to `UriDataSource` and pass that into ExoPlayer. That class has access to the `read()` method which all the bytes pass through. That method allows you to decrypt the files on the fly one buffer at a time.

In ExoPlayer 2.0, you supply your own custom `DataSource` from your own custom `DataSource.Factory` which can be passed to an `ExtractorMediaSource` (or any other `MediaSource`).

If you're not on ExoPlayer 2.0, you pass the `DataSource` to the `ExtractorSampleSource` and then to the `VideoRenderer` and the `AudioRender` in the `buildRenderers()` of a custom `RendererBuilder` that you implement.
(Also you can Google "custom datasource exoplayer" and that should give more info if what I provided isn't enough - or I can clarify if you can't find anything).

Here's a code snippet of the `read()` method:

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws IOException {
    if (bytesRemaining == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        try {
            long filePointer = randomAccessFile.getFilePointer();
            bytesRead =
                    randomAccessFile.read(buffer, offset, (int) Math.min(bytesRemaining, readLength));
            // Supply your decrypting logic here
            AesEncrypter.decrypt(buffer, offset, bytesRead, filePointer);
        } catch (EOFException eof) {
            Log.v("Woo", "End of randomAccessFile reached.");
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onBytesTransferred(bytesRead);
            }
        }
        return bytesRead;
    }
}
```

[EDIT] Also just found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925449/1759443) which has a similar suggestion.