# How to stream encrypted file using exoplayer (sample)?

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to stream encrypted audio file (.mp3),but I do not know how to achieve this. I am requesting a sample, or some form of direction to do that?. There is an issue here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2467
but it is discussing play local encrypted file.
Thanks for help.

Comment: this is answer for video might work for mp3 as well please check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458093/online-encrypted-streaming-video-files-with-aes-in-exoplayer-android

Comment: @Muhammad Alkady Did you find any solution?

Comment: Any solution regarding this?