# Online AES Encrypted Stream with ExoPlayer in Android

Tags: android, streaming, aes, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So I am a beginner to **ExoPlayer**, and I'm using *ExoPlayer v2.11.3* to play encrypted videos.
I've checked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458093/online-encrypted-streaming-video-files-with-aes-in-exoplayer-android), but it did not help me to do it since it is an old post since 2017!

What I think, that I need to create a custom DataSource from "`DefaultHttpDataSource`".

I'm using this "`Encrypt()`" method to do the AES encryption:

```
  private static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        if (hasFile()) {
            Log.d("Encrypt", "encrypted file found, no need to recreate");
            return;
        }
        // Video Reading.
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(toBeEncryptedFile);
        // This stream write the encrypted video. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
        // Create cipher
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            cos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom DataSource while overriding Open() and close(). You can create data input stream with the cipher initiated in the same method.